# Read file with mixed types (floats and strings)

Tags: python, numpy, io

I have a data file composed of `N` columns and `M` lines which I need to read storing each column into an array/list. The file is usually filled with numbers (floats) and in those cases I can just do:

```
import numpy as np
f_data = np.loadtxt('file.dat', unpack=True)
```

and the result is columns stored in `f_data` as sublists where its elements are `floats`,  as expected.

Other times the file can have random strings scattered around (see an example of such file [here](http://pastebin.com/igcYb4cb)) In those cases I need to read it in the same way (ie: unpacked with each column stored in a list/array and all elements in it stored as `float` type) with all the strings converted to a default float (for example `99.999`)

In the example of the data file above, the column `5` would look like this after reading it:

```
f_data[5]
[2.049, 0.946, 0.942, 0.889, 99.999, 0.879, 0.989, 1.142, 1.062, 0.551, 1.233, 0.503]
```

Notice that all elements are of type `float` and the string that was found was converted to `99.999` and also stored as a float.

`np.genfromtxt` is able to read a file with mixed types but the result is that all the floats are stored as strings, which is not what I need.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clearly implied fromt the context of the post. I'll make it more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.genfromtxt` is the answer, but it's a little bit tricky to get it working just right.

Try:

```
np.genfromtxt("file.txt", dtype=float, filling_values=99.99)
```

This forces the type to a float, in every case. When numpy finds a value that isn't a float, it declares this value invalid, and thus missing. Filling values gives a default answer for what to do when the data are missing, in your case, 99.99.

And, to edit as requested, to store column-wise, add unpack=True, making the total answer,

`np.genfromtxt("file.txt", dtype=float, filling_values=99.99, unpack=True)`

Comment: Excellent answer Joan! I wasn't aware of the `filling_values` option in `genfromtxt` and it works great. A minor edit to your answer so I can accept it: add `Unpack=True` so the file is stored column-wise instead of row-wise. Thank you!